# About the Boundary of Convex Sets under Linear Mappings

Tags: general-topology, convex-geometry

Let the set $\mathcal{S}$ be the Minkowski Sum of the two following sets, i.e. a Zonohedron ($\mathcal{Z}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$) and ($\mathcal{P}_O\cap\mathcal{B}(0,r)$), with $\mathcal{P}_O\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ being a Closed Convex Polyhedral Cone, pointed in $0$, and
$\mathcal{B}(0,\rho)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ the closed ball of radius $\rho>0$ and centre $0$. Clearly, $S$ is convex and compact.

My goal is to find the boundary of the set $\mathcal{T}$, related by a linear mapping to $\mathcal{S}$, i.e. $\mathcal{T}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^6\,|\,x=Ay, \forall y\in \mathcal{S}\}$. Both $\mathcal{S}$ and $A\in \mathbb{R}^{6\times3}$ are known in this problem. The matrix $A$ is given by:
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&-r_z&r_y\\
r_z&0&-r_x\\
-r_y&r_x&0
\end{bmatrix}$, where $(r_x,r_y,r_z)$ are the components of a given vector.

Generally, $\partial \mathcal{T}\ne A(\partial \mathcal{S})$ since $A$ is rectangular. However, is there any special case, i.e. sufficient condition, where the latter inequality holds as equality even with $A$ being rectangular? If not, any advice about how I may simplify the problem would be strongly helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $A$ injective?

Comment: It might be more productive to look at the relative boundary, as every point in $AS$ is on the boundary in $\mathbb{R}^6$. Note that $A \operatorname{ri} S = \operatorname{ri} (AS)$.

Comment: Yes, the matrix A is injective.
Thanks for both your question and your suggestion! I have amended the question a bit, adding the definition of the matrix A, whose blocks are an identity matrix and a skew-symmetric matrix.

Comment: If I have understood correctly, $S$ is compact and has a non empty interior, and so the boundary of $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ will be mapped to the relative boundary of $AS$ in $\mathbb{R}^6$.

Comment: Yes, S can never have empty interior. Indeed, the intersection of a ball, centred in 0 with positive radius and a cone, pointed in 0, gives non-empty intersection. The Zonohedron is, in turn, non-empty, so their Minkowski sum must be non-empty, as well.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by finding the boundary as **every** point in $AS$ is on the boundary (since it is contained in a strict subspace).